# Best way to apply least privilege to one specific jar application on Linux

Tags: linux, java, principle-of-least-privilege

Let's say I have some java application running on the host and do different things, and now I have built a jar that captures network traffic. While reading [What's a least-privilege way to allow node.js to access network adapters on Linux?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73950/whats-a-least-privilege-way-to-allow-node-js-to-access-network-adapters-on-linu), it seems to me that the best way to apply the least privilege is to do use setcap:

```
setcap 'cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip' /usr/local/bin/java
```

But here is the problem, if I setcap to Java, it then gives all java application to have ability to capture traffic. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper program that has those capabilities, that just starts `java` on the correct jar file.

Comment: Will this go back to the same problem? lets say I use a python script as a wrapper to start my jar, then my setcap will set python to have network capature ability.

Comment: @A.Ho a wrapper **program**, in a language that compiles to a native binary (e.g., C, C++, Rust, Haskell, etc.)